# AVR inline-assembly Fsin operand constraints

Tags: arduino, constraints, avr, inline-assembly

i am coding in arduino but i am also using assembly code between my c code. i want to calculate the sin of a value. so far i have this code:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  float answer;
  float angle = 2;
  int a = 2;
  int b = 3;
  asm("ADD %0,%1" : "+r"(a) : "r"(b)); 
  asm("fsin" : "=t" (answer) : "0" (angle));
  Serial.print(answer);
}
```

the error i get for this is: inconsistent operand constraints in an 'asm'
the funny thing is that i dont get this error when i remove the last line (Serial.print(answer))

also i found this code for a 8086 assembler and not avr and in 8086 "=t" is specific for floats but i cannot find anything similar for avr.

Comment: There is no such assembler command as `fsin` on an AVR. That is a C function call and needs to be handled as such (`CALL`).

Answer (score 1):

Whatever 8-bit AVR you are using almost certainly does not have an `fsin` instruction.  Since 8086 and AVR are two different architectures, they are going to have different instructions and also instructions with the same name might have different meanings.  You cannot expect to copy assembly code from one architecture to another.  The 8-bit AVRs do not have any native support for floating point numbers at all; that gets added in software by your compiler.

What you are looking for is the `sin` function provided by `avr-libc`.  This is just a normal C function that you can call by first adding `#include <math.h>` to the top of your program and then writing something like `answer = sin(angle);`.